# Azure Table Storage - 501 NotImplemented on CreateIfNotExistsAsync

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I'm using a storage account and account key/creds which I know to work: I have a blob container using exactly the same connection string which works fine.

I'm effectively doing this:

`CloudStorageAccount.Parse(_connectionString).CreateCloudTableClient().GetTableReference("MyTableHere").CreateIfNotExistsAsync().Wait()`

(I'm not in an async scenario, hence the wait.  Has nothing to do with this exception)

It throws an aggregate exception, the single inner exception is:

`Unexpected response code, Expected:OK or NotFound, Received:NotImplemented`

Deep in the exception:

`The requested operation is not implemented on the specified resource.
RequestId:30593945-0002-0019-0dde-3e30370003322
Time:2016-11-16T07:58:01.2396651Z`  - anonymised the request ID here.

Can't think what else to try!  Can't find any mention in the docs about any additional requirements here.

Comment: Can you please check the type of storage account? It should not be of type `BlobStorage` and also the redundancy type should not be of type `ZRS` or `Premium LRS`.

Comment: Works just fine for me on a ZRS storage account - http://i.imgur.com/PM1eezx.png

Comment: Nope, my bad, it was a LRS, ZRS doesn't work: `{"The remote name could not be resolved: 'zrs123.table.core.windows.net'"}` -- _As with the portal, the Service Management API also returns just the blob endpoint for the newly created account, since tables, queues and files are not supported for ZRS accounts_ (from https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2014/08/01/introducing-zone-redundant-storage/)

Comment: @GauravMantri - that was precisely the case, I had a BlobStorage account and not a general purpose one. The intro guides (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-create-storage-account#create-a-storage-account) don't seem to mention this, weirdly!  Feel free to post an answer here if you'd like, I'll accept it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tables (and also Queues & Files) are not supported by all kinds of storage accounts. As of today Tables, Queues and Files are not supported for `Blob Storage` kind of storage accounts.

Also for regular storage accounts, these services are not supported for accounts with following redundancy kinds: `ZRS` (only Block/Append blobs are supported) and `Premium LRS` (only Page blobs are supported).