# Azure storage account connection

Tags: f#, azure-storage

Having just created an Azure storage account with the following details:

- Location: UK West
- Subscription: Pay As You Go
- Performance/Access Tier: Standard/Hot
- Replication: Locally-Redundant storage (LRS)

The first thing I did was execute the following code (with my real account name and account key in place of MyAccountName and MyAccountKey) in an `F# FSI`.

```
open Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage
let connectionString = @"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=MyAccountName;AccountKey=MyAccountKey" 

CloudStorageAccount
   .Parse(connectionString)
   .CreateCloudTableClient()
   .ListTables()
   |> Seq.toArray
```

But I receive the following error:

`Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The remote server returned an error: (501) Not Implemented. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (501) Not Implemented.`

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Performance/Access Tier: Standard/Hot

According to the details you created your storage account, I assumed that your Account kind is `Blob storage`. As I known, Blob storage accounts are specialized for storing blob data. Based on your code, you need to re-create your Azure Storage Account and choose the `General purpose` for your account kind, which could provide storage for tables. Also, there is a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40627029/azure-table-storage-501-notimplemented-on-createifnotexistsasync), you could refer to it.

Comment: Thanks Bruce, changing the account type to `General Purpose` as opposed to `Blob Storage` did the trick.